# Describe a Dataframe on PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a fairly large Parquet file which I am loading using

```
file = spark.read.parquet('hdfs/directory/test.parquet')
```

Now I want to get some statistics (similar to pandas `describe()` function). What I've tried to do was:

```
file_pd = file.toPandas()
file_pd.describe()
```

but obviously this requires to load all the data in memory and it will fail. 
Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What are the stats you need? Spark has a similar feature

```
file.summary().show()
```

```
+-------+----+
|summary|test|
+-------+----+
|  count|   3|
|   mean| 2.0|
| stddev| 1.0|
|    min|   1|
|    25%|   1|
|    50%|   2|
|    75%|   3|
|    max|   3|
+-------+----+
```

Comment: how can I implement it when df has multiple columns type: string and float, as if I apply it, the output is not tidy and not good for visualization. Thanks in advance

Comment: I had the similar problem & and this is the great answer which helped me in avoiding memory issue. Although it's giving NULL as max, min if any column value contains NULL. While describe do not consider NULLs. Could someone give me any insights on how to handle NULLs and ignore them while calling summary()?

Comment: @ollik1, what if I want to get percentiles beyond the 25, 50, 75 default ones?

Answer (score 1):

In Spark you can use `df.describe()` or `df.summary()` to check statistical information.

The difference is that `df.summary()` returns the same information as `df.describe()` plus quartile information (25%, 50% and 75%).

If you want to delete string columns, you can use a list comprehension to access the values of `dtypes`, which returns a tuple ('column_name', 'column_type'), and delete the string type, passing these columns as a parameter to `df.select()`.

Command example:

```
df.select([col[0] for col in df.dtypes if col[1] != 'string']).describe().show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though its not exactly related to the question asked, but similar to `hive` or `SQL` based `describe` function to see `data types`, you can simple do

```
df.printSchema()
```

This will give you description of `data types` of the `data frame`